# Integrating a tensor over the whole of $R^3$

Tags: integration, tensors

I want to find $\int_{R^3}r^{-3}\exp^{-\lambda r^2}x_ix_jdV$ where $r = x_kx_k$.

I had the idea to translate that into finding $\delta_{ij}\int_{R^3}r^{-1}\exp^{-\lambda r^2}dV$

However, when I put the resulting integral in r into wolfram alpha, it gives me a really weird function.

This question is motivated by a problem I have to solve, so I think the answer should be quite neat.

Was my step wrong? I don't know where to go with this question.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates)?

Comment: Or even cylindrical?